# Error/convergence analysis using Taylor expansion for a root-finding method

Tags: numerical-methods, taylor-expansion, roots, nonlinear-analysis

I want to prove that this root-finding scheme has a quartic convergence rate
$$\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
y_{n}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime }(x_{n})}, n=0,1,2,...., \\
v_{n}=x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})-\frac{9}{30}f(y_{n})}{f(x_{n})-\frac{39}{30}%
f(y_{n})}\left( \frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime }(x_{n})}\right) , \\
x_{n+1}=v_{n}-\frac{f(v_{n})}{\frac{f(v_{n})-f(x_{n})}{v_{n}-x_{n}}}.%
\end{array}%
\right. $$
and the error below:
$$\mu _{n+1}=\frac{7b_{2}^{3}}{10}\mu ^{4}+O\left( \mu ^{5}\right), $$
where $\mu =x_{n}-\alpha $ and  $b_{k}=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{
f^{(k)}(\alpha )}{f^{\prime }(\alpha )}$,  $k=2,3,4,\ldots $.

For proof of that, we will use Taylor expansion first for $y_{n}$, then for $v_{n}$, and finally for $x_{n+1}$. I got it for $y_{n}$ successfully but for $v_{n}$, it was written that

$$v(x_{n})=\alpha +%
\frac{7}{10}b_{2}^{2}\mu ^{3}+\left( \frac{9b_{2}b_{3}}{5}-\frac{%
159b_{2}^{3}}{100}\right) \mu ^{4}+O\left( \mu ^{5}\right).$$

Now, how to get this relation for $v(x_{n})$?

My try for this purpose, I used Taylor expansion as follows

> $$f(x_{n})=f^{\prime }(\alpha )\left( \mu +b_{2}\mu^{2}+b_{3}\mu ^{3}+b_{4}\mu ^{4}+b_{5}\mu ^{5}\right)+O( \mu ^{6})$$
> and
> $$f^{\prime }(x_{n})=f^{\prime }(\alpha )\left( 1 +2b_{2}\mu+3b_{3}\mu ^{2}+4b_{4}\mu ^{3}+5b_{5}\mu ^{5}\right)+O( \mu ^{5})$$
> then I applied the binomial theorem with negative power to get that
> $$\frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime }(x_{n})}=\mu - b_{2}\mu
> ^{2}+\left( 2b_{2}^{2}-2b_{3}\right) \mu ^{3}+\mu ^{4}\left(
> -4b_{2}^{3}+7b_{3}b_{2}-3b_{4}\right) +O( \mu ^{5})$$
> So
> $$f(y_{n})=f\left( x_{n}-\frac{f(x_{n})}{f^{\prime }(x_{n})}\right)
> =f^{\prime }(\alpha )\left( b_{2}\mu ^{2}+\left( -2b_{2}^{2}+2b_{3}\right)
> \mu ^{3}+\left( 5b_{2}^{3}-7b_{3}b_{2}+3b_{4}\right) \mu ^{4}\right)+O( \mu ^{5}) $$

Then I got stuck here and I could not get that for $v(x_{n})$.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. You have given more story elements compared to the initial state of the question, but the beginning and the end are still missing. What is the iteration? Just the Newton method? What is the objective? Some finer exploration of the details of the quadratic convergence? Currently missing: what is $v(x_n)$, why does this expression get named/exhibited? Is $y_n=x_{n+1}$, and if not, why have the index $n$ at all if the iteration is not visible in the question?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I hope the above updated version of the question helps more

Comment: Yes, that is much better. Do you just want to prove the error formulas or also reconstruct the design of this method?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I want to prove the error formulas

Comment: @LutzLehmann Many thanks for your time and effort to write this detailed explanation for your approach and even your future ideas for improving the scheme

Answer (score 1):

#### rough outline of the method

The next value $x_{+1}$ is the secant root computed for the points $(x,f(x))$ and $(v,f(v))$. It is well-known that the error propagation for this is
$$
x_{+1}-\alpha = C\,(x-\alpha)(v-\alpha)~~\text{ or }~~ f(x_{+1})=C'\, f(x)f(v)
$$
To get an order $4$ error reduction, that is, $f(x_{+1})=O(f(x)^4)$ we need that $v$ is an order 3 approximation, $f(v)=O(f(x)^3)$. The Newton value $y=x+s$ has order 2. Its value $f(y)$ can be used to remove derivatives from third order methods like Halley's method
$$
v=x-\frac{f(x)f'(x)}{f'(x)^2-\frac12f''(x)f(x)}=x+\frac{f(x)}{f(x)-f(y)}s
$$
or the Euler-Chebyshev method
$$
v=x+s-\frac12f'(x)^{-1}f''(x)s^2=x+\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{f(x)}s
$$
or any variant in-between like in the proposed method.

#### Euler-Chebyshev method and variants in detail

Start with the Newton update $s=y-x=-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}$. Then any correction to it computes as $v=x+s+\gamma s$ with $\gamma  =O( f(x))$ and the function value
$$
f(y+\gamma s)=f(x)+f'(x)(s+\gamma s)+\frac12f''(x)(1+\gamma)^2s^2+...
\\
=-\gamma f(x)+\frac12f''(x)(1+2\gamma+\gamma^2)s^2+..
$$
This allows in a first step to replace $\frac12f''(x)s^2+...$ with $f(y)$. The remaining terms on the lowest order $O(f(x)^2)$ are $-\gamma f(x)+f(y)$, so set $\gamma =\frac{f(y)}{f(x)}$, with modifications of order $O(f(x)^2)$ possible, like $\gamma=\frac{f(y)}{f(x)+\kappa f(y)}$.

The first variant inserted gives the new leading error terms, now in order higher, as
\begin{align}
\frac{f(y)}{f(x)^2}&=\frac12\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)^2}+\frac16\frac{f'''(x)f(x)}{f'(x)^3}+\dots
\\
f(v)&=-f(y)+\frac12f''(x)\frac{(f(x)+f(y))^2}{f'(x)^2}+\frac16f'''(x)\frac{(f(x)+f(y))^3}{f'(x)^3}+\dots
\\
&=-f(y)+\left(\frac{f(y)}{f(x)^2}-\frac16\frac{f'''(x)f(x)}{f'(x)^3}\right)(f(x)+f(y))^2+\frac16f'''(x)\frac{(f(x)+f(y))^3}{f'(x)^3}+\dots
\\
&=2\frac{f(y)^2}{f(x)}\;+\;\frac{f(y)^3}{f(x)^2}+\frac16\frac{f'''(x)f(x)^2f(y)}{f'(x)^3}+\dots
\end{align}
Only the first term is of order 3.

#### Secant root

Translating the secant root error formula into  function values gives
$$
f(x_{+1})=\frac{f''(x)}{2f'(x)^2}f(x)f(v)+\dots
=2\frac{f(y)^3}{f(x)^2}+\dots
$$

Now you are free to replace $f(x)=\mu+b_2\mu^2+b_3\mu^3+...$, so that $f(y)=b_2\mu^2$ and $$f(x_{+1})=-2b_2^3\mu^4+...$$

I do not see where factors $5$ and $7$ or the value $\kappa=-\frac{39}{30}$ as an optimal parameter choice would originate.

#### Using CAS Magma for Taylor series computations

Using [computer algebra](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) for the Taylor series operations confirms the claim against above insights/objections.

```
CF<b2,b3,b4,b5>:=FunctionField(Rationals(),4);
A<k>:=FunctionField(CF);
PS<u>:=PowerSeriesRing(A);

f := u+b2*u^2+b3*u^3+b4*u^4+b5*u^5;
df := 1+2*b2*u+3*b3*u^2+4*b4*u^3+5*b5*u^4;

x := u+O(u^6);
fx := Evaluate(f,x);
dfx := Evaluate(df,x);

"Newton step";
s := PS!(-fx/dfx); "s = ", s;
y := x+s; "y = ", y;
fy := Evaluate(fx,y); "f(y) = ", fy;

"Chebyshev step";
gamma := 1+PS!(fy/(fx+k*fy)); "1+gamma = ", gamma;

v := x+gamma*s; "v = ", v;
fv := Evaluate(fx,v); "f(v) = ", fv;

"Secant root";
sr := PS!((u*fv-v*fx)/(fv-fx)); "secant root = ", sr;
"with value = ", Evaluate(fx,sr);
```

with output

```
Newton step

s =  -u + b2*u^2 + (-2*b2^2 + 2*b3)*u^3 + (4*b2^3 - 7*b2*b3 + 3*b4)*u^4 + 
    (-8*b2^4 + 20*b2^2*b3 - 10*b2*b4 - 6*b3^2 + 4*b5)*u^5 + O(u^6)
y =  b2*u^2 + (-2*b2^2 + 2*b3)*u^3 + (4*b2^3 - 7*b2*b3 + 3*b4)*u^4 + (-8*b2^4 + 
    20*b2^2*b3 - 10*b2*b4 - 6*b3^2 + 4*b5)*u^5 + O(u^6)
f(y) =  b2*u^2 + (-2*b2^2 + 2*b3)*u^3 + (5*b2^3 - 7*b2*b3 + 3*b4)*u^4 + 
    (-12*b2^4 + 24*b2^2*b3 - 10*b2*b4 - 6*b3^2 + 4*b5)*u^5 + O(u^6)

Chebyshev step

1+gamma =  1 + b2*u + (-b2^2*k - 3*b2^2 + 2*b3)*u^2 + (b2^3*k^2 + (6*b2^3 - 
    4*b2*b3)*k + (8*b2^3 - 10*b2*b3 + 3*b4))*u^3 + (-b2^4*k^3 + (-9*b2^4 + 
    6*b2^2*b3)*k^2 + (-25*b2^4 + 32*b2^2*b3 - 6*b2*b4 - 4*b3^2)*k - 20*b2^4 + 
    37*b2^2*b3 - 14*b2*b4 - 8*b3^2 + 4*b5)*u^4 + O(u^5)
v =  (b2^2*k + 2*b2^2)*u^3 + (-b2^3*k^2 + (-7*b2^3 + 4*b2*b3)*k - 9*b2^3 + 
    7*b2*b3)*u^4 + (b2^4*k^3 + (10*b2^4 - 6*b2^2*b3)*k^2 + (33*b2^4 - 38*b2^2*b3
    + 6*b2*b4 + 4*b3^2)*k + (30*b2^4 - 44*b2^2*b3 + 10*b2*b4 + 6*b3^2))*u^5 + 
    O(u^6)
f(v) =  (b2^2*k + 2*b2^2)*u^3 + (-b2^3*k^2 + (-7*b2^3 + 4*b2*b3)*k - 9*b2^3 + 
    7*b2*b3)*u^4 + (b2^4*k^3 + (10*b2^4 - 6*b2^2*b3)*k^2 + (33*b2^4 - 38*b2^2*b3
    + 6*b2*b4 + 4*b3^2)*k + (30*b2^4 - 44*b2^2*b3 + 10*b2*b4 + 6*b3^2))*u^5 + 
    O(u^6)

Secant root

secant root =  (b2^3*k + 2*b2^3)*u^4 + (-b2^4*k^2 + (-8*b2^4 + 5*b2^2*b3)*k - 
    11*b2^4 + 9*b2^2*b3)*u^5 + O(u^6)
with value =  (b2^3*k + 2*b2^3)*u^4 + (-b2^4*k^2 + (-8*b2^4 + 5*b2^2*b3)*k - 
    11*b2^4 + 9*b2^2*b3)*u^5 + O(u^6)
```

#### Higher order?

Looking at the leading coefficient, the variant with $k=\kappa=-2$ increases the order in $v$. Then computing the secant from the points $y$ and $v$ gives a method of order $6$, which is better than 2 Newton steps with less evaluation effort for it. 2 Newton steps followed by a secant step gives the same order,  but with more evaluations.